# Validate empty date input?

Tags: javascript

I'm simply trying to check if a `text` and `date` input are not empty before being inserted into an object. If both of them are empty, I would like them to not be added to it. Yet any attempt I make, they still are added to the object with no value.

```
for(let i = 0; i < otherDeps.length; i++) {
      let obj;
      if(otherDeps[i].name && otherDeps[i].dob != "") { //Here
        obj = {
          name: otherDeps[i].value,
          dob: otherDepsAge[i].value
        };
      }
      otherDepsArray.push(obj);
    }
```

I have tried `if(!otherDeps[i].date)`, `ìf(otherDeps[i]name != '' && otherDeps[i].date != '0000-00-00')`

Anyone know the correct way to go about this?

Comment: Mostly it depends on how your **empty** data looks like (0, null, undefined, "", ..). Else move the `push` into the condition, else it is always going to add atleast an empty object. An alternative would be using [array#filter](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter).

Comment: I moved the push into the condition and the same thing happens.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

These are the two conditions you need to check for an invalid date or not a right date:

- `theDate.value`
- `isNaN(new Date(theDate).getTime())`

Putting this into the perspective, we can do something like:

```js
function checkDate() {
  var theDate = document.getElementById("date").value;
  if (theDate.trim() === "" || isNaN(new Date(theDate).getTime())) {
    console.log("Invalid Date!");
  } else {
    console.log("Valid Date!");
  }
}
```

```html
<input type="date" id="date" />
<button onclick="checkDate()">Check Date</button>
```

In your `for` loop, wrap the date's value inside the `checkDate()` condition above. This should work.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to check if the inputted date is invalid or empty, you can use the validity.badInput property of the HTMLInputElement:

```js
submit = () => {
    const date = document.getElementById('my-date');
    if (date.value === '') {
      if (date.validity.badInput) {
        console.log('Invalid');
      } else {
        console.log('Blank');
      }
    } else {
      console.log(date.value);
    }
  }
```

```html
<input type="date" id="my-date" />
<button onClick="submit()">Submit</button>
```